# How do I access the process.env object of the importing class in an imported npm package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I have a react app that sets a bunch of process.env variables using dotenv.  Every component when it's source is in the same source code repo and imported via '../component/component_name' can access the process.env variables simply by using process.env.variable_name.  We decided to break the components out into separate NPM packages in order to update them independent of the main repo.  Now when we import them from our local NPM they intsall to node_modules and run, but cannot access the process.env variables.  process.env shows up as an object, but it has nothing in it.  We are using webpack to build the package before we publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Inside component, you can do:

```js
import process from "process";

const env = process.env;

export default env;
```

Comment: This does not do anything.  In app.js I can access process.env.API_URL, but if I try to access process.env.API_URL in a component from node_modules, it will return undefined same as before without these lines.

Comment: If you use => import process from "process"; console.log(process.env), <= inside components from node_modules, is returning undefined?

Comment: It is returning an empty object.

Comment: A info that I find after some searching (can be useful): when you build/transpile a node module, you cant read "process.env" data.